# Cannot access robots.txt file in ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, robots.txt

I am working on MERN stack project using keystone. I am trying to access robots.txt file but it is giving me error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

I've put robots.txt file in root directory and also tried to keep inside

> routes>robots.txt

but it is not able to access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the `robots.txt` file in the `public` folder instead, with the static option set to `public`. `'static': 'public'`

Comment: try to add also your serveur implementation, without any code it's difficult to help you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create `robots.txt` into a route, you could put it in e.g. the `public` directory instead, with the `static` option set to `public`.

```
keystone.init({
  static: 'public',
  // ...
});
```